# VBA Excel 2010 - LN function for a range

Tags: excel, vba

when i'm using LN function in excel it allows me to select a range, yet when trying to use the same function in vba the argument must be double, how to tackle this problem?

```
        On Error Resume Next

            Application.EnableEvents = False
            With Sheets("Stale")

                    ostatnia = .Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

                    Set zakres = Range(.Cells(6, 6), .Cells(6, ostatnia))
                    Set zakres2 = Range(.Cells(5, 6), .Cells(5, ostatnia))

                     ***`logarytm = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ln(zakres2)`***

                        nachylenie = Application.WorksheetFunction.Slope(zakres, zakres2)

                    MsgBox nachylenie & " $$ " & logarytm

            End With

            Application.EnableEvents = True

        On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Hard to understand what you mean by "the argument must be double".

Comment: i ment the type of data

Comment: Did my Answer not work for you? did you get an error when trying `logarytm = Evaluate("Ln(" & zakres2.Address & ")")` ?

Comment: no it does not work, when i change "zakres2" to a singular cell it's ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do exactly what excel is doing when the formula in normally entered:

```
logarytm = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ln(CDbl(zakres2.Cells(1, 1)))
```

Then in VBA you could simply use:

```
logarytm = [Ln(A3:A9)]
```

In your issue if you want to use a Range Variable your simpliest solution would be:

```
logarytm = Evaluate("Ln(" & zakres2.Address & ")")
```

Comment: that would be very nice but the data are taken from a pivot

Comment: @antyinteligent What does a Pivot have to do with anything?

Comment: then i don't quite understand what do you mean by inputing a formula

the funny whing is that i get different results depending whether i use the function in excel or this logarytm = [Ln(A3:A9)]

Comment: and one more thing: when using LN in excel it picks one number from the range and calculates the ln from it, do you maybe know on what basis does it choose it?

Comment: When you enter `=Ln(A3:A9)` in B1 or B2 or B10+ you will get an error a `#VALUE` error, but if you enter it in B3:B9 you will get the same as `LN(AThisRow)`

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2013, it's true, you can set the LN() to point to a range, but in fact it only uses that value of the first cell in the range.

This is what the VBA is allowing you to do: it wants the value to apply the number to. (And indeed, what is the LN of a list of numbers when put into one cell?)

Answer (score 0):

From [Norie](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/415054-ln-num-log-num-base-visual-basic-applications.html):

```
LN is not a native VBA math function, but you can access it using Application.WorksheetFunction.

Log in VBA only takes one parameter.

But if you use Application.WorksheetFunction you access the LOG worksheet function which takes more parameters.

Log in VBA is the natural logarithim, whereas the LOG worksheet function has the 2nd parameter to specify the base, which if omitted defaults to 10.
```